# How can I get variables from my Theme with styled components and use within astroturf css

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, styled-components, astroturf

I've come across a "problem" which is making me feel like I've chosen the wrong stack for what I'd like. I'm pretty new with React & Typescript but I wondered if anyone knew of a way too do the following.

#### theme.ts

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"
import { ThemeType } from "../types/theme"

export const lightTheme = {
    background: "#F2F3EF",
    text: "#252524",
}

export const darkTheme = {
    background: "#1C282B",
    text: "#F2F3EF",
}

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle<{ theme: ThemeType }>`
  body {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 300px;
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.background};
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text};
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Roboto, sans-serif;
  }
`
```

#### styles.ts

```
import { css } from "astroturf"
import { useTheme } from "styled-components"

const theme = useTheme()

const styles = css`
    .navContainer {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .themeToggle {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .logo {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .menuItems {
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        a.light:hover {
            background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background};
        }
        a.dark:hover {
            background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background};
        }
    }
`
export default styles
```

I get the following error message, which DOES make sense

> Could not resolve interpolation to a value, css returned class name,
> or styled component.             All interpolated styled components
> must be in the same file and values must be statically determinable at
> compile time

I'm running webpack with postcss but also, trying to use themes from style-components.
The end goal is to use a toggle switch to change theme from light/dark but I just need some guidance on what approach I should be taking. Clearly implementing css-in-js with astroturf for postcss is going to be problematic with the way I've used themes but I wanted to ask you guys before I tear it out.

There could be an easy solution which I'm missing. I have tried just importing the variables light and dark and then trying to use those within my css string but, this also doesnt work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot just call `useTheme()` outside of a component as this is a violation of the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).  Your `styles` are not a constant value as they need to respond to changes in the current theme, so I don't know if you can do this at compile time.  I don't know enough about astroturf to give you an answer with astroturf.  [I can do it with just styled-components](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-theming-g9jgg?file=/src/App.tsx).  Does that help?

Comment: What you are trying to do with separate styles based on class name "light" or "dark" should work if you use the values directly like `${darkTheme.background}` instead of `${({ theme }) => theme.background}`.  But you have to add that class name in your HTML/JSX.  I would move the class name way up in the tree so that you only have to write it once and I would use "theme-light" / "theme-dark" so there's no ambiguity.  Then you can target links which are descendants of "theme-dark" like `.theme-dark > a:hover`.

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste Yes! you're right with the first problem of useTheme() I did come to that conclusion with this. Which is why I tried to switch to a class method and import the different theme colours based on just a variable like you have displayed but for some reason I get the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined``` :( 
As for moving the classes up higher, christ that would be much simpler thank you!!!!